# Read Web.Config values into non .net html page for environment situations

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, visual-studio, deployment

We have an Angular project we want to be independent of .NET, but it will be inside a VS project because the client is a .NET shop.  Is there a way to read values from the Web.config where they can set environment variables for deployments that can go into an Angular page without it being Razor or Form based? Any type of work around?

Answer (score 1):

You can expose the settings through a service that you can call via ajax from angular. 
The service can be a simple http based api like asp.net web api etc.

Comment: Where would you store the url that would call that?  We could have a dev, staging and production server.